# Does Visual Studio 2010 let you edit icons?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, icons

When I double click on a .ico file in Visual Studio 2010 (Professional), it opens what looks like an icon editor.  It looks like it should be really easy to pick a color from the left and edit pixels.

But my mouse is a magnifying glass icon.  Left click, right click, all they do is toggle zoom on the icon.  I can't figure out how to do anything useful.

Am I missing something obvious?  Is this icon view as useless as it seems?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Doh!  I needed to enable View -> Toolbars -> Image Editor.

Thanks to @detale.

Comment: Mine toolbar icons but magnifying glass are greyed out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27):

You can't directly edit 32-bit color icons but you can convert them manually to 24-bit :

```
Right click > Add new icon
```

Open your `Icon1.ico` file.

`Right click > New Image Type` or press `Ins` to open the `New Icon Image Type` dialog.

Select the format you want, say `96x96, 24 bit` or add any custom size and color depth.

Then copy/paste from your 32-bit icon file and save.

Et voilà ! You can now edit your 24-bit color icon.

Comment: This destroys alpha transparency.

Comment: @SLaks You just have to set the magic transparency color in your favorite image editor.

Comment: @hoang What is that supposed to mean? Converting png to 24 bit bitmaps removes the transparency and there is no documented way to get it back.

Answer (score 7):

The icon is built by an external app.

For Visual Studio 2008 & 2010 image editor,
"Using the Image Editor, you can view 32-bit images, but you cannot edit them."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1dadd79.aspx

Comment: Does that mean I can edit non-32-bit images?  (What a maddeningly un-informative documentation line.)

Comment: For non-32-bit images, you can select tools alongside the magnifier to edit the image.

Comment: You can do edit them. See the following link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12634/How-to-Create-Icon-Files-for-Your-Windows-App-usin

Comment: @coolcake: that only shows 8-bit images as highest colour quality. This answer was specifically about 32-bit images.

Answer (score 4):

For the PNG images used as button icons that Visual Studio cannot edit you can use external editor as MS Paint.

- open PNG in Visual Studio 2010
- right click on the white canvas -> Open External Editor

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio can edit icons, but not 24-bit color icons.

Comment: When I right-click and add a new icon, it makes a 4-bit icon, and I still can't edit it.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot select Pencil Tool from the toolbar?

Comment: Ah!  That's what I needed to see!  The toolbar wasn't visible, and I didn't know to look for it.

Comment: Did you mean *But not 32-bit color icons* ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac OS X machine around, you can edit Windows icons with the Icon Composer application included with the free Developer Tools.

I just discovered this accidentally while working on some cross-platform Mac/Windows code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an easy way to do it without visual studio, GIMP
https://www.gimp.org/downloads/

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: I know, but since I kept searching allover online and came up by 2 questions over stackoverflow but still got stuck with no answer.. if VS didn't work it out (no c++ installed), found it would be useful for anyone facing the same as i faced

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 (available free) has an icon editor built in. Just in case you end up here because you tried to insert a colourful image into a a 256x256 24 bit icon and your colours get messed up: in the editor toolbar on the top right there is a selector for opaque/transparent background, but **only** when you have a **rectangle-** or **irregular area selection tool** active. Default backgroundis set to transparent, you need to set it to **opaque** to retain your image. (There's a special colour for transparency; though my image does not contain that the colours were wrong)